# Error: Module does not exist when clicking links in sugarcrm CE

Tags: php, error-handling, sugarcrm

At the moment when I click any module link in the menu it comes up saying "Error: Module  does not exist." However I can still access the module by typing the link in the address bar.
**(dir/index.php?module=&action=index&return_module=&return_action=DetailView)**

This also happens in list view when clicking on the links for a record.

Please help me !

Thanks

*Sugar CE Version 6.5.16 (Build 1082)*

Comment: Is it a stock/vanilla system or have you made some customization to it?

Comment: Sorry I dont know what you mean? Ive just done a reinstall due to some problems and installed a custom module that I made?

Comment: I just mean for you to state what customization/module you've done, and you answered. I'd be curious to know what is in the custom module you made to see if that's the source of the issue.

Comment: It holds customer information only. Im looking to modify it so that it can hold document files for each record/customer eventully but it would be good to have it just working for now

Comment: Just done a clean fresh install everythings working fine untill I upload the module. The module is very basic it has customer name adress ect. has pension details and a notes bit at the end. Alot of fields. Think I should start again or try work out whats wrong ?

Comment: I bet you have something wrong in your file system permissions. Try to just chmod 777 /cache and /custom and /modules just to see if that fixes it (obviously that's not good for production). Then do a repair & rebuild and see what happens.